# Cloning local git repositories

Tags: git, clone

I'm having a strange issue when trying to clone a local repository on a build server.

My repository lets say is at `/opt/git/repos/my_repo.git`

Doing a `git clone /opt/git/repos/my_repo.git` is very fast

However if I edit my `.gitconfig`

Add the following:

```
[url "/opt/git/repos/"]
    insteadOf = "gitserver:"
```

Then try:

`git clone gitserver:my_repo.git` this is very slow

UPDATE:

The flag --local or -l have no effect. Git seems to default to a remote repository.

In fact it treats the gitserver: alias as a remote git server. Does any have a workaround for this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, it may be trying to lookup "/opt/git/repos" in DNS.  Perhaps try `[url file:///opt/git/repos/]`.  Still might not work though if it's actually trying to lookup gitserver instead.  You also may want to use the --local flag.

Comment: I suspect that using the `--local` flag would do it.  In fact, the difference between `/path` and `file:///path` is that the former implies `--local` while the latter does not.

Comment: The easiest solution to this is probably to use a shell function, rather than a git substitution.